# Android Storage Access Framework: How to edit a file from my app that implements DocumentsProvider

Tags: android, file, android-contentprovider, edit

I've implemented a DocumentsProvider in my app. This allows me to view and edit my app's files from another app (e.g. QuickOffice) that implements the Storage Access Framework client code.

I could already open a file from my app in another app to allow viewing of the file from my app. The one piece still missing seems to be the ability for my app to open a file for editing in another app and having the file written back to my app when it is saved in the client (in the same way the file is written back when opening the file from the client app using the SAF).

Is this currently possible?

This question is related to [Android: How do I open a file from my app for editing in QuickOffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747107/android-how-do-i-open-a-file-from-my-app-for-editing-in-quickoffice).